# how to add listener for markerclusterer finished loading?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, addeventlistener, markerclusterer

I already added a map load listener after which i start adding markers to the cluster.
I wanna display a loading screen till the markerclusterer finishes the marker loading.
so how do i do that ?
this is my hide loading screen code which hides on map tiles load.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
$("#loading").hide();
});
```

Comment: How do you add the markers?

Comment: This s how i add markers to map

        **var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                             position: myLatlng,
                             operator:data.Operator,
                             map: map,
                             icon: performanceIcon,
                             optimized: false
                });

         cluster.push(marker);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's an old one but for anyone in the same situation I sort of found a solution.

Right after you are creating your cluster

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map,
    markers,
    {
        imagePath:
            "/img/m/"
    });
```

Add a listener for 'zoom_changed' like that:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,
    'zoom_changed',
    function(event) {
        console.log("zoom occured");
    });
```

(The listener once being key here, you don't want it to run every time the user zooms, you don't even need to set a different zoom value, nothing will happen visually)

and then:

```
map.setZoom(10);
```

I am using the same value (10) as in my InitMap function, so the user doesn't see any zoom in or outs.